# Which is the expected behavior trying to get an undefined mapping value?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, mapping

In ERC20 standard, *_allowed* is defined as:

```
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowed;
```

and the getter function is defined as:

```
function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _allowed[owner][spender];
}
```

I'm testing the function, and calling allowance(*address1*, *address2*) I receive 0. Why is that happening? The keys *address1*, and *address2* were not initialized in *_allowed*.

I was expecting a KeyError, like in another languages, (python, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/types.html#mappings):

> You can think of mappings as hash tables, which are virtually
>   initialised such that every possible key exists and is mapped to a
>   value whose byte-representation is all zeros, a type’s default value.

And regarding the default values [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/control-structures.html#scoping-and-declarations), it states:

> A variable which is declared will have an initial default value whose
>   byte-representation is all zeros. The “default values” of variables
>   are the typical “zero-state” of whatever the type is. For example, the
>   default value for a bool is false. The default value for the uint or
>   int types is 0. For statically-sized arrays and bytes1 to bytes32,
>   each individual element will be initialized to the default value
>   corresponding to its type. Finally, for dynamically-sized arrays,
>   bytes and string, the default value is an empty array or string.

So you are getting default initialized value of `uint256` i.e. `0`.